# Pandas - calculating difference in two hex integer color values

Tags: python, pandas, integer, hex, rgb

I am attempting to calculate differences in integer hex values. My df as formatted as such:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['0xD8E3ED', 2043441], ['0xF7F4EB', 912788],['0x000000',6169]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c_code', 'occurence'])
df['value'] = df['c_code'].apply(int, base=16)
```

Now I would like to add a color difference to my df with help from

[coldiff.py](https://gist.github.com/fikr4n/368f2f2070e0f9a15fb4)

I am able to run the following with success

```
(cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(14214125))))
18.41431752537279

(cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(df['value'].iloc[0]))))
18.41431752537279
```

But when I attempt to run through the rows of my dataframe I get the following error

```
df['diff'] = (cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(df['value']))))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-521a6c3f607f> in <module>
----> 1 df['diff'] = (cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(df['value']))))
      2 df

<ipython-input-2-ce2d615c99ef> in rgb(x)
     40     if isinstance(x, str) and x[0] == '#':
     41         x = int(x[1:], 16)
---> 42     return ((x >> 16) & 0xff, (x >> 8) & 0xff, (x) & 0xff)
     43 
     44 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'Series' and 'int'
```

I believe that this is from the df rows not being read in as integers but I am unsure of how to resolve it or why .iloc[0] seems to solve the issue. I have tried running as a loop with .iloc[i] but cannot seem to resolve the issue. Additionally, using a .apply(int) method within rgb() produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a row-by-row evaluation using `apply` with `axis=1`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (cie94(rgb2lab(rgb(13227184)), rgb2lab(rgb(x['value'])))), axis=1)

0    18.414318
1    15.444622
2    83.892102
```

Comment: that does it! thank you! just curious, what does the apply function change here?

Comment: The apply does really change anything.  It returns a `Series` that then could be added to the existing DF.  Like `df['new_value'] = df.apply(..., axis=1)`